# Nested JSON parsing

Tags: java, json, parsing

I have the following [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) string

```
 String JSON = {"IP":{"string":"1.2.3.4"},"UrlParameters":{"map":{"pw":"36","mu":"www.abc.com"}}}
```

I need to get the value of pw and mu in Java. How do I parse it?

Comment: Using a JSON parsing library.

Comment: my parser is not working for some reason. I am trying to use org.json.JSONObject

Comment: Okay, so why isn't it working?

Comment: Show us your parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     String JSON = "{\"IP\":{\"string\":\"1.2.3.4\"},\"UrlParameters\":{\"map\":{\"pw\":\"36\",\"mu\":\"www.abc.com\"}}}";

     JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(JSON);
     System.out.println("Full JSON String: "+jsonObject);

     JSONObject urlParametersMap = jsonObject.getJSONObject("UrlParameters").getJSONObject("map");
     System.out.println("mu: "+urlParametersMap.getString("mu"));
     System.out.println("pw: "+urlParametersMap.getString("pw"));
}
```